# how to get intersection set data for an array?

Tags: javascript

i need the intersection set within an array. How can I do that?(I'll only take type 1 and 2.)

```
var arr = [
    {
        id: 1, auths: [
            { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' },
            { authId: 2, type: 1, value: 'Test2' },
            { authId: 3, type: 2, value: 'Test3' },
            { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' },
            { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2, auths: [
            { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' },
            { authId: 2, type: 1, value: 'Test2' },
            { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' },
            { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3, auths: [
            { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' },
            { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' },
            { authId: 5, type: 1, value: 'Test5' },
            { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4, auths: [
            { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' },
            { authId: 3, type: 2, value: 'Test3' },
            { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' },
            { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' }
        ]
    }
]
```

and the output i wanted

```
var outArr = [
    { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' },
    { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }
]
```

i was try this;

```
arr.map(p=>p.auths).filter(x=> arr.map(p=>p.auths).includes(x))
```

and this;

```
var _map=arr.map(p=>p.auths);
_map.filter(({authId:id1})=> _map.some(({authId:id2})=> id2!==id1))
```

I tried a few more things but it didn't work. I don't want to use a loop. How can I do this without using a loop?

Comment: Can you explain what the exact conditions are? You want all types 1 and 2 but not duplicates, am I correct?

Comment: But are you sure that `{ authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }` is on intersection result? note that in  first array this object has `type: 1`: `{ authId: 4, type: 1, value: 'Test4' }`. I don't think this object should comes out from intersection

Comment: yes you'r right @Wimanicesir

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I edited, I made a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
var arr = [ { id: 1, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 2, type: 1, value: 'Test2' }, { authId: 3, type: 2, value: 'Test3' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] }, { id: 2, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 2, type: 1, value: 'Test2' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] }, { id: 3, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 5, type: 1, value: 'Test5' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] }, { id: 4, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 3, type: 2, value: 'Test3' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] } ];

let intersectedArray = arr.map(x => x.auths)[0];
arr.map(x => x.auths).map(arr => {
   intersectedArray = intersectedArray.filter(n => {
      return arr.map(el => {return n.authId === el.authId && n.type === el.type && n.value === el.value;}).includes(true)
   });
})
console.log(intersectedArray)
```

`map` the `auths` arrays, then `map` again by filtering an inner `map` that checks if elements are equal.

If you want only elements of type 1,2 just add a condition on inner `map`:

```js
var arr = [ { id: 1, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 2, type: 1, value: 'Test2' }, { authId: 3, type: 2, value: 'Test3' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] }, { id: 2, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 2, type: 1, value: 'Test2' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] }, { id: 3, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 5, type: 1, value: 'Test5' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] }, { id: 4, auths: [ { authId: 1, type: 1, value: 'Test1' }, { authId: 3, type: 2, value: 'Test3' }, { authId: 4, type: 2, value: 'Test4' }, { authId: 99, type: 3, value: 'Test' } ] } ];

let intersectedArray = arr.map(x => x.auths)[0];
arr.map(x => x.auths).map(arr => {
   intersectedArray = intersectedArray.filter(n => {
      return arr.map(el => {return n.authId === el.authId && n.type === el.type && n.value === el.value && el.type !== 3;}).includes(true)
   });
})
console.log(intersectedArray)
```